# Using array to replace string

Tags: c#, arrays, streamreader

I have a two arrays i have taken from a csv file, i want to check my current output for the first array and output the second array, eg
"Hello, LOL" would output "Hello, Laugh out loud" 
i have used

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@filelocation"));
List<string> listA = new List<string>();
List<string> listB = new List<string>();

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(',');

    listA.Add(values[0]);
    listB.Add(values[1]);
}
```

The arrays are stored and have the correct information in them, i just don't know how to check a string from the first list and change it to the second.

Comment: Could you please show us a sample of the csv file's content? I don't understand why you need two arrays? Why not have all the information in one?

Comment: b4, Before
BC, Because

I have no idea why i have them in two arrays, i don't know what i'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) for this operation instead of List. In addition, you could use [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) to read all lines in a file instead of looping.

```
// I replace your code with linq
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = 
  File.ReadAllLines("@filelocation").Select(l => l.Split(',')).ToDictionary(k =>
k[0], v => v[1]); 

string input = "Hello, LOL" ; 

var thekey =  dictionary.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => input.Contains(k));

if (thekey != null) // Replacement was found 
{
    input = input.Replace(thekey, dictionary[thekey]);    
}

// Should print Hello, Laugh out loud
Console.WriteLine(input) ;
```

Comment: i already have the values stored that i want to change, ListA holds all the abbreviations and listB holds the full words, i want to check my input and if something from listA is found swap it to listB

for example an input could be "yes, LOL" and it would check the input through list A output would be "yes, laugh out loud" because "LOL" turns into "laugh out loud"